# How to find $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x^2+2\cos x-2}{x \sin^3x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to evaluate 
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2+2\cos x-2}{x \sin^3x}?$$

I tried using L'Hospital but it seemed that there is an infinite loop of 0/0 form

Comment: Hint/suggestion: try going term by term.

Comment: You should not get an infinite loop of $0/0$ using L'Hopital. The derivatives of the numerator are

$$2x-2\sin x,\quad 2-2\cos x,\quad 2\sin x,\quad\text{and}\quad2\cos x$$

at which point the limit in the numerator is $2\cos0=2$, not $0$. The derivatives of the denominator are similarly straightforward, albeit increasingly tedious, to compute.

Comment: Use [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto0%7D%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E2%2B2%5Ccos%20x-2%7D%7Bx%20%5Csin%5E3x%7D%24&p=1) before answering a standard exercise, please.

Answer (score 2):

Using that $\cos x= 1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{24}+o(x^6)$, and $\sin x=x+o(x^3)$, 
$$
\frac{(x^2+2\cos x-2)}{(x \sin^3x)}
=\frac{x^4/12+o(x^6)}{x(x+o(x^3))^3}
=\frac{x^4/12+o(x^6)}{x^4+o(x^6)}
=\frac{1/12+o(x^2)}{1+o(x^2)}\xrightarrow[x\to0]{}\frac1{12}. 
$$

Answer (score 2):

Use Taylor series for $\cos x$ about $x=0$

$$\cos x = 1 -x^2/2+x^4/24 -... $$

Thus  $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(x^2+2\cos x-2)}{(x \sin^3x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^4}{12x \sin^3x} =\frac {1}{12}$$

Answer (score 1):

All that is needed is
$\sin(x)
=x-x^3/6+O(x^5)
=x(1-x^2/6+O(x^4))
$
so
$\sin^2(x)
=x^2(1-x^2/3+O(x^4))
$
and
$\sin^3(x)
=x^3(1-x^2/2+O(x^4))
$.

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{(x^2+2\cos x-2)}{x \sin^3x}
&=\dfrac{x^2+2(\cos x-1)}{x \sin^3x}\\
&=\dfrac{x^2+2(-2\sin^2(x/2)}{x \sin^3x}\\
&=\dfrac{x^2-4\sin^2(x/2)}{x \sin^3x}\\
&=\dfrac{x^2-4(x/2)^2(1-(x/2)^2/3+O(x^4))}{x\cdot x^3(1-x^2/2+O(x^4))}\\
&=\dfrac{x^2-x^2(1-x^2/12+O(x^4))}{x^4(1-x^2/2+O(x^4))}\\
&=\dfrac{x^4/12+O(x^6))}{x^4(1-x^2/2+O(x^4))}\\
&=\dfrac{1/12+O(x^2))}{1-x^2/2+O(x^4)}\\
&\to 1/12\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

For the L'Hospital's rule, use $\sin x\sim x \Rightarrow \sin^3x \sim x^3, x\to0$:
$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2+2\cos x-2}{x \sin^3x}&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2+2\cos x-2}{x^4}\stackrel{LR}=\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x-2\sin x}{4x^3}\stackrel{LR}=\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2-2\cos x}{12x^2}\stackrel{LR}=\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2\sin x}{24x}=\\
&=\frac{1}{12}.\end{align}$$